# ProFTPD/vsftpd readonly/readwrite access depending on connection source?

Tags: ftp, proftpd

Is there any possibility to configure ProFTPD that way:

User has read/write FTP access to his home directory

If User connects from inside LAN (e.g. 172.16.0.0) he should have full access (read/write) as usual

If User connects from outside (from internet, or any other network) he should have read only access.

Both cases User should have same login/password

Only one instance of ProFTPD should be active.
Instead ProFTPD we can use vsftpd, if it is neccesary.

Is there any ideas to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the ProFTPD configuration, you can set up some [ACLs](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/ConnectionACLs.html) based on the connection origin. Therefore, you just have to put a [Limits](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Limit.html) directive on read/write commands and define the correct ACLs.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for pointer! Solution was: `    <Limit WRITE>
        Allow from 172.16.0.0/20
        DenyAll
    </Limit>
`